# For IPv6 address with multiple equal length consecutive zero blocks, which one should be compressed?

Tags: ipv6

ex:

```
1:0:0:4:0:0:7:8
1::4:0:0:7:8
1:0:0:4::7:8
```

Read somewhere the left most should win tiebreaker.  Is that correct?  Is there a standard/requirement?  From RFC 5952 2.2 it appears one can chose which group to compress.

If there is no standard/requirement, what are the pros/cons to left or right?
Is there a convention?

Comment: Please use the network prefix IANA has set aside for examples: `2001:db8::/32`

Answer (score 2):

*[RFC 5952, A Recommendation for IPv6 Address Text Representation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952)*, which is a Standards Track RFC, explains that when given the choice of two equal-length, consecutive zero blocks, you must compress the leftmost zero block.

> 4.2.3.  Choice in Placement of "::"
>
> When there is an alternative choice in the placement of a "::", the
> longest run of consecutive 16-bit 0 fields MUST be shortened (i.e.,
> the sequence with three consecutive zero fields is shortened in 2001:
> 0:0:1:0:0:0:1). ***When the length of the consecutive 16-bit 0 fields are
> equal (i.e., 2001:db8:0:0:1:0:0:1), the first sequence of zero bits
> MUST be shortened. For example, 2001:db8::1:0:0:1 is correct
> representation.***

Comment: So which is correct?  Section 2.2 
This gives a choice on where in a single address to compress the zero.
2001:db8::aaaa:0:0:1
2001:db8:0:0:aaaa::1
or section 4.2.3?

Comment: Section 2 is showing the problem of the flexibility of RFC 4291, but Section 4 is the recommendation of RFC 5952. As it explains, an application or device must accept any valid RFC 4291 IPv6 address, but should return an IPv6 address in the RFC 5952 format of Section 4.